# How do i detect collision betwen two animated balls?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, collision-detection, game-physics

I'm trying to make a simple shooter, but I have some problems with  detecting collisions between the  shots and the enemy  (blue balls). I have tried several things, but  I can't figure it out

Can someone pliz please help me?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var tileldig = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);
    var tekst = document.getElementById("tekst")

    var kuler = [
        {r: 10, x: canvas.width/2, y: canvas.height-100, f: "red", dy:0},
        //{r: 50, x: tileldig, y: 50, vx:0 , vy: 3, f: "green"},
    ]



    var fiender = [
        {r: 20, x: tileldig, y: -20, vx:0 , vy: 1, },
    ]
    /*var skudder = [
        {r: 10, x:0+kuler.x, y: 0+kuler.y, f: "black"},
    ]*/




    function spill() {

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        for (var i = 0; i < kuler.length; i++) { 
            kuler[i].x += 0;
            kuler[i].y += kuler[i].dy;


            ctx.fillStyle = kuler[i].f;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(kuler[i].x, kuler[i].y, kuler[i].r, 2*Math.PI, 0);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();




            if (kuler[0].x >= canvas.width-kuler[0].r) {
                kuler[0].x = canvas.width-kuler[0].r
            };
            if (kuler[0].x <= 0+kuler[0].r) {
                kuler[0].x = 0+kuler[0].r
            };
            if (kuler[0].y >= canvas.height-kuler[0].r) {
                kuler[0].y = canvas.height-kuler[0].r
            };
            if (kuler[0].y <= 0+kuler[0].r) {
                kuler[0].y = 0+kuler[0].r
            };



        for (var j = 0; j < fiender.length; j++) { 
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(fiender[j].x, fiender[j].y, fiender[j].r, 2*Math.PI, 0);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();

            fiender[j].y += fiender[j].vy;

            if (fiender[j].y >= canvas.height) {
                fiender.splice(j,1);
                console.log("ute");
            };  


            if (fiender[j].y + fiender[j].r >= kuler[i].y && fiender[j].x + fiender[j].r == kuler[i].x) { // remove kuler[i] and fiender[j] } 
                fiender.splice(j, 1);
                kuler.splice(i,1);
            };

            if(j > 1){ 
                fiender.splice(j,1)

            }


        }
    }




        document.onkeydown = function tast (e) {            
          switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
              kuler[0].x -= 10;
              break;
            case 39:
              kuler[0].x += 10;
              break;
            case 38:
              kuler[0].y -= 10;
              break;
            case 40:
              kuler[0].y += 10;
              break;
             case 32:
              newskudd()
              console.log("hit space")
              break;
          }
        };




        requestAnimationFrame(spill);
    }

    function newskudd () {
        var nyttskudd = 
        {x:kuler[0].x, y:kuler[0].y, r:5, dy:-5, f:"black"};
        kuler.push(nyttskudd);
    };

    setInterval(
        function(){
            fiender.push({r: 20, x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1), y: -20, vx:0 , vy: 1, f: "green"});
    }, 1000);



    spill();

    /*for (var i = 0; i < kuler.length; i++) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < fiender.length; j++) { 
            if (kuler[i].y >= fiender[j].y) { // remove kuler[i] and fiender[j] } 
        }; 
    }*/
    /*if (circles.x >= canvas.height- circles.r){
        circles.splice(i,1);
    }*/
```

If you want to see a demo, click the link: [DEMO](http://elevweb.akershus-fk.no/~stmo0403/it2/spill/)

Comment: Where in your code are you attempting to detect a collision?

Comment: i trying it at  line 71-74

Comment: help a brother out. We don't see line numbers. Which lines are they?

Comment: Calculate the distance between the centers of the two balls you want to test, using the Pythagorean theorem.  If that distance is less than or equal to the sum of the radii, you have a collision.

Comment: if (fiender[j].y + fiender[j].r >= kuler[i].y && fiender[j].x + fiender[j].r == kuler[i].x) { // remove kuler[i] and fiender[j] } 
   fiender.splice(j, 1);
   kuler.splice(i,1);
  };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditional should look like:

```
var distanceFromCenters = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(fiender[j].x - kuler[i].x),2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(fiender[j].y - kuler[i].y),2 );
if (distanceFromCenters <= (fiender[j].r + kuler[i].r)) {
    // you have a collision
```